# MySQL how change columns and rows in table?

Tags: mysql

I have got next table:

```
date            3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24     
2015.01.01      3 2 5  2  5  7  2  4
2015.01.02      9 3 1  3  4  6  4  1
2015.01.03      0 2 3  1  5  6  3  4
```

I need to get table like:

```
date                  time          numbers
2015.01.01            03:00:00       3
2015.01.01            06:00:00       2
2015.01.01            09:00:00       5
2015.01.01            12:00:00       2
2015.01.01            15:00:00       5
2015.01.01            18:00:00       7
2015.01.01            21:00:00       2
2015.01.01            24:00:00       4
2015.01.02            03:00:00       9
2015.01.02            06:00:00       3
```

How I can do it?

Comment: Add the columnnames of original table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach with `union all`:

```
select `date`, '3:00:00' as `time`, `3` as val from yourtable
union all select `date`, '6:00:00' as `time`, `6` as val from yourtable
union all select `date`, '9:00:00' as `time`, `9` as val from yourtable
...
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfe87/1)

BTW, I'd highly recommend renaming your columns...

---

Here's another approach using conditional aggregation and a `cross join`:

```
select `date`, val as `time`, 
  max(case when val = 3 then `3`
           when val = 6 then `6`
           when val = 9 then `9`
      end) as `val`
from yourtable cross join (select 3 val union all select 6 union all select 9) t
group by `date`, val
```

- [More Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfe87/3)